# Adding a ContentPage as a Child

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a ContentPage to a Grid programatically, but Grid.Children only accepts Views.. How do I display this page as a child of another element?

Answer (score 3):

You can't display a page within a Grid.  Try using a ContentView instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a page in a grid.
What are you trying to achieve?